# Makefile - How to save the .o one directory up?

Tags: makefile

Imagine the following folder structure:

- project

  - src

    - code.c
    - makefile
  - bin

How can I compile code.c to code.o and directly put it inside bin? I know I could compile it to code.o under src and the do "mv code.o ../bin" but that would yield an error if there were compile errors, right? Even if it works that way, is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: The better way is to not use `make` which is painfull as hell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process should or should not "yield an error" depending on what you mean. If there are compiler errors, you'll know it.

That said, there are several ways to do it with make. The best in this case are probably:

- You could put the Makefile in bin. Make is good at using files *there* to make files *here*, but not the other way around.

  You could specify the target path in the makefile target:

  ```
  $(MAIN_DIR)/bin/%.o: %.c
      $(COMPILE)...
  ```

Comment: You can also use `../bin/%.o: %.c` as a pattern rule in the Makefile, so you might be able to avoid an explicit `$(MAIN_DIR)` variable.

Comment: @Dale Hagglund: I thought of that, but it makes the Makefile less flexible. For instance, you can't move it to a different directory.

Comment: True enough.  In larger makefile systems, I usually end up with a `rules.mk` file somewhere at the top of the tree that I include in lower-level makefiles.  `rules.mk` would contain a pattern rule like this.  The actual makefiles still aren't strictly location-independent, of course, since I have to edit the necessary include paths if I copy them around.

Comment: @Dale Hagglund: you can make the lower-level makefiles (somewhat) movable either by using absolute, not relative paths in the include directives, or by using the -I option when you run make, to tell it where to look.

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but if it can be helpful.
This is how I get the up one level directory path from where the makefile is.

```
$(subst $(notdir $(CURDIR)),,$(CURDIR))
```

if your project looks like that:

```
~/myProject/
    src/
        Makefile
        #all the .c and .cpp
    bin/
        #where you want to put the binaries.
```

$(CURDIR) will output ~/myProject/src

$(subst $(notdir $(CURDIR)),,$(CURDIR)) will output ~/myProject

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving, but only when the compilation was successful using `&&`:

```
code.o: code.c code.h
    g++ -c code.c && mv code.o ../
```

`mv code.o ../` will only be executed if `g++` returned 0, which is when the compilation was successful. This may not be suitable solution for you if you have very complicated `makefile`, but I thought I'd share what I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the move approach and survive compiler errors:

```
cc -c code.c && mv code.o ../bin
```

This won't run the "mv" part if the "cc" part fails.